# Multiple Google maps in bootstrap tabs not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, maps

to make it easier (I hope) I made a bootply to show what's going wrong.

Basically;

The first tab is fine.

The second tab is shown as the same address (but it's not, not even the same Latitude/Longitude). Also notice that the window doesn't get centered anymore to where the marker is.

The third tab is just not centered either on the right spot.

I hope you have enough information and that someone can help me, thanks a lot in advance!

Here's the bootply link. http://www.bootply.com/dnUvptXSMP

Comment: Not much since my knowledge of javascript is minimal :

Comment: We are not a tutorial service. See the rules, you need to demonstrate a minimum comprehension of the task you need help with. I would suggest reading google map docs here-> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/